# Xquery only returning a single record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery, xquery-sql

I've been trying to scrape information out of an Extended event I wrote in SQL2008r2 in an attempt to create some better form of error tracking on SQL.

I eventually got one *working* after a lot of trial and error, however it only seems to return the first row. I'm trying to read the information into a CTE so I can then do additional processing on the data and return it in a different format

What I've written

```
;with events_cte as(
select
DATEADD(mi,
DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
xevents.event_data.value('(RingBufferTarget/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) AS [Timestamp],
xevents.event_data.value('(RingBufferTarget/event/data[@name="severity"]/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Error Severity],
xevents.event_data.value('(RingBufferTarget/event/data[@name="message"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)') AS [Error Message],
xevents.event_data.value('(RingBufferTarget/event/action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [SQL Text],
xevents.event_data.value('(RingBufferTarget/event/action[@name="username"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [Username],
xevents.event_data.value('(RingBufferTarget/event/action[@name="database_id"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [DatabaseID]
From(Select CAST(xet.target_data AS xml) as event_data
FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets xet
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions xe
              ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address) 
WHERE xe.name = 'what_queries_are_failing') as xevents)
```

What I'm working with (an example)

```
    <RingBufferTarget eventsPerSec="0" processingTime="0" totalEventsProcessed="55" eventCount="55" droppedCount="0" memoryUsed="161803">
      <event name="error_reported" package="sqlserver" id="100" version="1" timestamp="2016-12-15T01:42:59.361Z">
        <data name="error">
          <type name="int32" package="package0" />
          <value>50000</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <data name="severity">
          <type name="int32" package="package0" />
          <value>16</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <data name="state">
          <type name="int32" package="package0" />
          <value>1</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <data name="user_defined">
          <type name="boolean" package="package0" />
          <value>true</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <data name="message">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>User Defined Exception!!!</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <action name="client_hostname" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>hostname</value>
          <text />
        </action>
        <action name="database_id" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="uint16" package="package0" />
          <value>1</value>
          <text />
        </action>
        <action name="sql_text" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>RAISERROR('User Defined Exception!!!', 16, 1) 
    </value>
          <text />
        </action>
        <action name="tsql_stack" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>&lt;frame level='1' handle='0x010001001561AB09005F28B1000000000000000000000000' line='1' offsetStart='0' offsetEnd='-1'/&gt;</value>
          <text />
        </action>
        <action name="username" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>user</value>
          <text />
        </action>
      </event>
      <event name="error_reported" package="sqlserver" id="100" version="1" timestamp="2016-12-15T01:42:59.361Z">
        <data name="error">
          <type name="int32" package="package0" />
          <value>50000</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <data name="severity">
          <type name="int32" package="package0" />
          <value>16</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <data name="state">
          <type name="int32" package="package0" />
          <value>1</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <data name="user_defined">
          <type name="boolean" package="package0" />
          <value>true</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <data name="message">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>User Defined Exception!!!</value>
          <text />
        </data>
        <action name="client_hostname" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>hostname</value>
          <text />
        </action>
        <action name="database_id" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="uint16" package="package0" />
          <value>1</value>
          <text />
        </action>
        <action name="sql_text" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>RAISERROR('User Defined Exception!!!', 16, 1) 
    </value>
          <text />
        </action>
        <action name="tsql_stack" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>&lt;frame level='1' handle='0x010001001561AB09005F28B1000000000000000000000000' line='1' offsetStart='0' offsetEnd='-1'/&gt;</value>
          <text />
        </action>
        <action name="username" package="sqlserver">
          <type name="unicode_string" package="package0" />
          <value>user</value>
          <text />
        </action>
      </event>
</RingBufferTarget>
```

What I get: Only seems to return one row, could it be the CTE?

So my question is:

How can I get the rest of the records in the XML to be pulled through?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following changes:

[1]

```
FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets xet
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions xe ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address) 
       OUTER APPLY xevents.event_data.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event') AS x(XmlCol)
```

[2] from

```
xevents.event_data.value('(RingBufferTarget/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) AS [Timestamp],
xevents.event_data.value('(RingBufferTarget/event/data[@name="severity"]/value...
```

to

```
x.XmlCol.value('(@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) AS [Timestamp],
x.XmlCol.value('(data[@name="severity"]/value...
```